# I need a real UNIX RoR development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, ubuntu

From the beginning, I am a Windows master.  I started with MS-DOS.  I put up Windows 2.1 and every Windows since.  I have 10 different Windows boxes running in my house right now, from Windows 7 Ultimate to varied flavors of Windows Servers. I haven't done Windows 8 and don't want to go there.

I have UNIX experience with both servers and varied software, but it hasn't been my preferred environment.  However, I guess I am converting.  I've tried to pretend to run UNIX under Windows using Cygwin and MSYS.  My purpose is to build a development environment.  Both have failed me.  I have spent more time trying to fix a series of technical issues than I have developing.  That is unacceptable.

My Ruby on Rails development environment is by far my highest current priority.  I have websites to build, right now.

At this point, I have two options.  One is to find a UNIX development environment in a cloud.  The other is to convert one of my many machines to a true UNIX system. So, I need advice.  I don't really want to build and babysit a system. The idea of a cloud-based development environment is very interesting, with the caveat that I don't chase it down another rat hole like I have with Cygwin and MSYS.

Here are the questions.  Is there a solid cloud-based Ruby on Rails friendly development environment out there?  Failing that, should I put up an Ubuntu-based system.  If I go there, do I convert a workstation or a server?

Thanks...

Comment: It's clearly programming-related, and while it is on the fringe of the prohibited *what's the best?* discussion questions, the case of RoR is a bit special. If you Google, you will be told that Windows works. But, no one uses it, so really it doesn't, and you are outside the community. Questions like this need SW developer responses and SO is the only place to get that. Now, I will say that this question has been asked here on SO before. If you must close it, link to a duplicate.

Comment: I dont think a cloud-based development is a good idea to start, you need a local machine that can run a development version of your work ,otherwise you gonna have a bad time.

Comment: I will rather you have a fresh copy of Ubuntu 12.04 or Linux mint in your local. That will make your dev all the more easier(since your real focus is on dev).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Externally, I have received a recommendation for EngineYard.com as an outstanding RoR environment and will ultimately consider it as my primary development/migration/production environment.

I have a working Debian system now and am building it out as a local RoR environment.  It just seems to be right for a serious RoR development environment.  I will go there as soon as it is fully built out because RoR is just meant for UNIX.

However, at least temporarily, I have found that RubyStack is a seriously usable Windows RoR development environment.  It is 100% usable as a standalone system that doesn't require UNIX-style environments shoehorned onto Windows.  Trying to run UNIX on Windows was a constant source of frustration, so this meets my immediate needs.

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/). I use this to do development on my Windows systems.

Comment: I looked a Vagrant and it left too many questions.  It appears to be a blackbox VM-style environment.  This level of complexity, considering what I already experienced, makes me nervous.  I am looking for more straight forward solutions.  I could be wrong, but the documentation just didn't give me good answers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As you found out, Windows is terrible for RoR development. Your best option would be to use a VM like VirtualBox to run a Linux/Unix instance. There are other VM options, but VirtualBox is free.

Failing that, just convert once of your boxes to Linux/Unix. For development it does not matter one bit if it is a workstation or a server.

Comment: VM looked to be another layer of complexity.  Debian does seem to be an answer.

Answer (score 3):

#### Mac OSX

The unofficial standard for RoR production is Linux, but for development it is Mac OSX. There has been a big migration of developers to the Apple platform that has been going on for many years now.

It gives you the best of both worlds: it is Unix underneath but it's also a commercial platform, a polished UI, and an available software ecosystem.

Yes, it's expensive, but people should ask themselves, *why are people willing to pay so much?* If you can afford 10 boxes for Windows, how about finding $ for one Mac?  Then, you will have not just a workable RoR environment, but the best.

#### Or go VM

But if you don't take that advice, you may want to install a Hypervisor like [Xen](http://www.xen.org/) or [XenServer](http://www.citrix.com/products/xenserver.html) for free, and then you can run both Windows *and* Linux on the same machine. This is slightly different than running a VM *under* Windows.

Comment: I would never consider OSX as a good solution.  My ultimate environment would be UNIX, so that doesn't fit.  And, VM just adds complexity when I can use a real machine.  Thanks.